# Can you use hashed data in a random forest classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm using hashed data to build a random forest classifier in Python (sklearn) to classify hacker intrusion events. Some of the variables are hashed, for example, IP addresses, and they have a lot of levels (over 19K, for a database of 23K events). I am intending to use these variables as categorical variables, so that IPs associated with a hacker intrusion once, can later be used to classify other events as hacker intrusions or not. I don't think I would be able to reduce the dimensionality of the data or use some sort of clustering analysis since it is hashed. For example, if I had 150 levels for a country variable, I could reduce it to continents. But, since it is hashed, I am unsure PCA or other dimensionality reduction method would be helpful.

However, given the enormous amount of levels in this variables, I am unsure if I should input this variable as a categorical variable or transform it into an ordinal variable. I have read that when a categorical variable has a lot of levels, it could be better to transform it into an ordinal and (especially with a large sample like mine).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the scale of the information. If there is some ordinal relationship to IP addresses, then leveraging that ordinality makes sense. In the absence of ordinality, it makes no sense whatsoever. For instance, suppose the NFL had hundreds of football teams with no implicit ranking. Converting that nominally scaled variable into an ordinally scaled metric simply for the sake of convenience would be total garbage.

One of the convenient facts about RFs is that nominally scaled factors with many levels are still feasible. This is due to the fact that the process of resampling and selection acts as an automatic brake on the possible number of levels, generally ensuring that the memory limitations of the hardware aren't exceeded. Of course, if the number of levels is so massive that this breaks down, then some additional constraints will need to be imposed.